# Building a dynamic WHERE filer in PySpark (DataBricks)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

So I'm trying to dynamically load a set of SQL Server tables from info in DataBricks (the company's lakehouse for info) using Python / PySpark. I'm trying to make it as dynamic / data-driven as possible, so I'm trying to build out a dynamic WHERE to filter a dataframe with. Because each pull from the lakehouse will have a different date column to filter by, I need to be able to use both variables for the column to filter on, as well as variables for the dates in question.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
where_condition = "((" + check_column + " > '" + start_date_str + "') & (" + check_column + " < '" + end_date_str + "'))"
      
filtered_df = df.where(where_condition)
```

But I get back the following error:

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve '((`l0_createTime_` > CAST('2022-11-01' AS TIMESTAMP)) & (`l0_createTime_` < CAST('2022-11-02' AS TIMESTAMP)))' due to data type mismatch: '((`l0_createTime_` > CAST('2022-11-01' AS TIMESTAMP)) & (`l0_createTime_` < CAST('2022-11-02' AS TIMESTAMP)))' requires integral type, not boolean; line 1 pos 1;
```

I feel like I'm missing something (obviously)... I've tried multiple ways of building the where statement, but it's not seeing it as such.

Any suggestions on how to build something dynamic like this, containing both dynamic columns from the dataframe, as well as dynamic values to compare to those dynamic columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&` operator, in Spark SQL, is for [bitwise AND](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/api/sql/index.html#_4) and requires integral operands, as the error says.

What you want to use here is the [logical AND](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/api/sql/index.html#and) operator, that is `AND`:

```py
where_condition = "((" + check_column + " > '" + start_date_str + "') AND (" + check_column + " < '" + end_date_str + "'))"
```

---

A cleaner way to build your dynamic condition is to use PySpark API:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
where_condition = (F.col(check_column) > start_date_str) & (F.col(check_column) < end_date_str)
filtered_df = df.where(where_condition)
```

in this case the `&` operator is used, which is an overloaded operator in the [PySpark Column class](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/column.html).

Comment: Sorry about the delay in getting back to you! Thank you very much, this is perfect!